# get meta tags is not working in php

Tags: php, gzip, meta-tags

I am trying to get meta tags of a website. Here is my code

```
 $tags = get_meta_tags('https://www.wired.com/story/avengers-infinity-war-d23-footage'); 
   print_r($tags); exit;
```

this returns empty. Any idea?

Wesbite is using some compression like gzip.

Comment: check if your php.ini has "allow_url_fopen" setting turned off. That might be the reason for get_meta_tags() returning empty array. Try enabling the "allow_url_fopen"

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti : it is already enabled. website is using gzip compression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decompress it, which you can use a [stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) for. E.g.:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('compress.zlib://https://www.wired.com/story/avengers-infinity-war-d23-footage');
print_r($tags);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [viewport] => width=device-width, initial-scale=1
    [content-type] => article
    ...
)
```